# Apache2 Only Showing Default Page/Unlimited Redirects

Tags: apache, apache2, server, reverse-proxy

I am using a reverse proxy to show my bitwarden site. Here is the .conf in my sites enabled:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName bitwarden.example.com
        Redirect "/" "https://bitwarden.example.com/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName bitwarden.example.com
        ProxyPreserveHost on
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile {REDACTED}
        SSLCertificateKeyFile {REDACTED}
        SSLCertificateChainFile {REDACTED}
        ProxyPass / http://10.0.0.98:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.0.98:8080/
        #RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
</VirtualHost>
```

We have several problems with this:

1. When I go to the site, I get unlimited redirects
2. Even when I comment out the Redirect line in port 80, going to `https://bitwarden.example.com` will only display the default "It Works" apache2 webpage
3. `http://10.0.0.98:8080/` is a valid localhost IP on my server. Hitting `curl http://10.0.0.98:8080/` on the server will show the correct bitwarden website we are trying to show
4. A records for bitwarden.example.com have been added on CF, it goes to the webserver

Answer (score 2):

You're probably asking on the wrong site - serverfault would be a better place than this.

It's not Apache returning the redirects, it's bitwarden.

> curl http://10.0.0.98:8080/ on the server will show the correct bitwarden website

That's rather surprising - I imagine if you change your environment so that http://bitwarden.example.com/ and make a request with a realistic browser user-agent you'll see the redirect.

Just a certificate on bitwarden & switch off the validation in Apache (SSLProxyVerify none + SSLProxyCheckPeerCN Off + SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire Off)